# Why the physical meaning of quantum hall effect is important?

Tags: quantum-hall-effect

I have read some paper about transport measurement of graphene.

From classical hall effect, we can get some information about kind of charge carrier, charge density etc.

So, it is important for understanding matter.

But, I don't know why quantum hall effect is important in graphene transport measurement.

Its consequence is just a quantization of conductance and by this quantization, we can conclude this electronic system is just a 2D.

Comment: That last sentence would seem to be a pretty important physical meaning, don't you think?